# how do i solve this differentiation question?

Tags: derivatives

please help me with the question.I have tried numerous times but I cant seem to find the answer.
Differentiate the given function and simplify your answer.

$ y  =  (4x^4 + 7x^2 − 4)^3 $

Comment: If that is the multiplication sign, then the answer is 0. Derivative of a constant

Comment: oh I am sorry,its the following equation    (4x^4 + 7x^2 − 4)^3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We start with $y  =  (4x^4 + 7x^2 − 4)^3$
We know that the Chain Rule says that $[u(v)]' = u'(v)\cdot v'$, and so we set $u=x^3, \quad v=4x^4 + 7x^2 − 4, \quad u' = 3x^2, \quad v' = 16x^3 + 14x$
Combining these, we get $\color{red}{3(4x^4 + 7x^2 − 4)^2(16x^3 + 14x)}$ as our answer. If you mess around with this you'll find it also equals $6 (4 x^4+7 x^2-4)^2 x (8 x^2+7)$ (you take a factor of two out of the binomial) and $768 x^{11}+3360 x^9+3168 x^7-1974 x^5-1584 x^3+672 x$ (the expanded form)

Comment: @Dan May I ask who downvoted this answer? I can't find any errors with it. Also, Dan: if this answered your question please accept it so the question can be closed, or even accept the other answer if you prefer it. Not accepting answers on questions is bad practice in general, unless there is a reason for it.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen The math checks out

Answer (score 0):

EDITED

You use Chain Rule

$ y' = 3 (4x^4 + 7x^2 - 4)^2(16x^3 + 14x)$

We typically don't expand from here but if the answer did, do so.

Comment: I tried that but it isn't the answer

Comment: I'm not being cocky or anything, but the answer could be wrong. Perhaps post the answer? EDIT: I just realized you wanted it to the power of 3, let me correct this for you.